# Accessing relationship field in emberjs template?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Here is the current structure that i have on my `emberjs` model

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  team: DS.belongsTo('team'),
  opponent: DS.belongsTo('team'),
  type: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

and the template that i am calling it from is as follows

```
  <div class="container">
    {{#each model as |match|}}
      <div class="match">
        <code>Match type : {{match.type}}</code>
        <p>Team 1 : {{match.team.name}}</p>
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
```

Now the `match.team` returns me a promise. My question is how do i render the `name` on template side.

> The `team` with proper id was already populates with model api call as
>   relationship.

### EDIT

The problem is that the Promise resolved to no content. The following is the json response

```
{
  "meta": {
    "type": "match"
  },
  "included": [{
    "type": "team",
    "id": 3,
    "attributes": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "teamName",
      "logo": null,
      "created-at": "2018-06-05T07:05:42.000Z",
      "updated-at": "2018-06-05T07:05:42.000Z"
    }
  }],
  "data": [{
    "id": 1124639,
    "type": "match",
    "attributes": {
      "id": 1124639,
      "team": 77,
      "opponent": 1,
      "starts-on": "2018-06-10T00:00:00.000Z",
      "created-at": "2018-06-05T08:30:13.000Z",
      "updated-at": "2018-06-05T08:30:13.000Z",
      "relationships": {
        "team": {
          "data": {
            "id": 77,
            "name": "teamName",
            "logo": null,
            "created-at": "2018-06-05T07:05:57.000Z",
            "updated-at": "2018-06-05T07:05:57.000Z",
            "type": "team"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

I am assuming something is wrong with the structure for `relationships` but can't get my finger on what exactly ?

Comment: This should work. Does the team have a name?

Comment: @Gaurav i just realized that the promise resolves the empty content. Let me edit the question to add json response as well.

Comment: This isn't a standard JSON-API response. I would suggest fixing your server's response to return the team in the "included" section with the correct id (77). However, if you cannot do so, you can use the EmbeddedRecordsMixin to help you write a serializer that can handle a nonstandard api on the client.

Comment: Ok i can change the server. Can you point out a sample diff or something on which part i am going wrong at ?

Comment: Also the numbers are just representation as i had to minify the json response to keep that short.

Comment: Answered. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resonse shown isn't standard JSON-API. You wan't something that looks like this:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "type": "match"
  },
  "included": [{
    "type": "team",
    "id": 77,
    "attributes": {
      "id": 77,
      "name": "teamName",
      "logo": null,
      "created-at": "2018-06-05T07:05:42.000Z",
      "updated-at": "2018-06-05T07:05:42.000Z"
    }
  }],
  "data": [{
    "id": 1124639,
    "type": "match",
    "attributes": {
      "id": 1124639,
      "opponent": 1,
      "starts-on": "2018-06-10T00:00:00.000Z",
      "created-at": "2018-06-05T08:30:13.000Z",
      "updated-at": "2018-06-05T08:30:13.000Z"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "team": {
        "data": {
          "id": 77,
          "type": "team"
        }
      }
    }
  }]
}
```